# Cache previously downloaded layers when pulling

Tags: docker

I was pulling [a large Docker configuration:](https://hub.docker.com/r/kaggle/python/~/dockerfile/)

```
docker pull kaggle/python
```

For some reason, it got stuck after most layers were downloaded:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from kaggle/python
85b1f47fba49: Already exists
603f9c6eacba: Already exists
501f1d57b2bc: Already exists
6db69dab30a3: Already exists
7d1d88783781: Pull complete
d9cf29229181: Pull complete
e91d72eeb564: Pull complete
5bd7f2695a28: Pull complete
ea5661ca20d6: Pull complete
65ac9698f4e0: Pull complete
fefaaa277a96: Pull complete
a6ccb48c5a47: Downloading [=========================================>         ] 774.8 MB/930.5 MB
0bae91a5cc80: Download complete
a6d225a434fd: Download complete
12a36693ef4a: Download complete
c1de1c338a84: Download complete
1ef14c075913: Download complete
7eb2c80a4abf: Download complete
5c0b94551445: Download complete
e06ff6eb486b: Download complete
b0571c0ec206: Download complete
304d85a90c3a: Download complete
b6aa745ea7b4: Download complete
9863e05179fe: Download complete
```

Because of this, I cancelled the process and started pulling again `docker pull kaggle/python`:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from kaggle/python
85b1f47fba49: Already exists
603f9c6eacba: Already exists
501f1d57b2bc: Already exists
6db69dab30a3: Already exists
7d1d88783781: Pull complete
d9cf29229181: Pull complete
e91d72eeb564: Downloading [===========>                                       ] 353.1 MB/1.536 GB
5bd7f2695a28: Downloading [===============>                                   ]   357 MB/1.163 GB
ea5661ca20d6: Download complete
65ac9698f4e0: Downloading [======================>                            ] 287.7 MB/629.1 MB
fefaaa277a96: Waiting
a6ccb48c5a47: Waiting
0bae91a5cc80: Waiting
a6d225a434fd: Waiting
12a36693ef4a: Waiting
c1de1c338a84: Waiting
1ef14c075913: Waiting
7eb2c80a4abf: Waiting
5c0b94551445: Waiting
e06ff6eb486b: Waiting
b0571c0ec206: Waiting
304d85a90c3a: Waiting
b6aa745ea7b4: Waiting
9863e05179fe: Waiting
```

The problem is that Docker starts downloading the layers that have already been downloaded. Is there a way to prevent this?

Can I tell Docker to cache the layers and then look in the cache before downloading them again?